# Inline Boxed Equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, boxes

I'm having trouble producing a boxed equation in the same line as some other formulae. For example: `$$ \frac{2}{4} =\[\boxed{ \frac{1}{2} }\] $$`

I'd like to be able to show some calculations, followed by a boxed final answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard LaTeX command for boxing something is `\fbox`.   Its argument is in text mode; to switch to display format mathematics you need to issue

```
\fbox{$\displaystyle  ... $}
```

Thus your example becomes

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{2}{4} =\fbox{$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$} \]

\end{document}
```

producing

[image: Sample output]

If you are using `amsmath` then its `\boxed` command (thanks daleif for the link) already takes care of switching to maths and display style, so you just write the code for the math object directly between the braces `{...}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{2}{4} = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}} \]

\end{document}
```

In other words in the argument to `\boxed` you do not need math mode switching commands such as `\[..\]`.

Comment: The boxed command the op is already using should be fine, it already sets the contents in math mode.  The math syntax the op is using is just messed up

Comment: @daleif `\boxed` needs some package - which?

Comment: Standard part of `amsmath`

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick is as follow:

```
   $$\frac{1}{1+ \text{\boxed{$$\frac{1}{1+x}$$}}}$$
```